# Angular.io / Angular 4. How do I refresh one component view when triggering another

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple Angular.io app. (angular-cli / 4.1.0)

I have a NavbarComponent that renders the username.

When accessing the app the first time I am not logged in and my app redirects to the LoginComponent. My NavBar is also rendered but without a username. After successful login I am redirected to my HomeComponent.

And here is the problem. My NavBar does not show the username. But if I do a refresh/ctrl+r the username is rendered.

What is wrong?

app.component.html

```ts
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

navbar.compoment.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  me;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.me = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }
}
```

login.component.ts

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { AlertService, AuthenticationService } from '../_services/index';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    model: any = {};
    loading = false;
    returnUrl: string;

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
        private alertService: AlertService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.authenticationService.logout();

        // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    login() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.authenticationService.login(this.model.email, this.model.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.error(error);
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.errorMsg = 'Bad username or password';console.error('An error occurred', error);
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by JusMalcolm, `OnInit` doesn't run again.

But you could use a `Subject` to tell the `NavbarComponent` to fetch the data from local storage.

In your `NavBarComponent` import `Subject` and declare it:

```ts
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

....

public static updateUserStatus: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
```

Then subscribe in your constructor:

```ts
constructor(...) {
   NavbarComponent.updateUserStatus.subscribe(res => {
     this.me = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
   })
}
```

And in your `LoginComponent`, import your `NavbarComponent` and when you have successfully logged in, just call `next()` on the Subject, and `NavbarComponent` will subscribe to it.

```ts
.subscribe(
   data => {
      NavbarComponent.updateUserStatus.next(true); // here!
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
   },
   // more code here
```

Also you can use a shared Service to tell `NavbarComponent` to re-execute the retrieval of the user. More about shared service from the [**Official Docs**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

Comment: Thank you AJT_82 and @JusMalcolm. I will try your suggestions here, I think that the shared service you mention may be the "best practice" way to go. However I think it is a shame that there is not a more practical (read: easy) way to do it. You should be able to call the a type of zone refresh or an app.module refresh that looks at the route and reloads all components in the route.

Comment: but the user again disappears on reload

Comment: @SaquibulHassan Yes, it does, this question did not ask for persisted data on page refresh, so that is why it is not included. You need to for example use local storage to persist the data when page is refreshed :)

Comment: yeah i did it 

Answer (score 0):

Since the component has already been initialized, ngOnInit() does not run after logging in. One solution for your case is to subscribe to a router param that checks whether the user is logged in.

eg.

```
this.route.queryParams
        .map(params => params['loggedIn'])
        .subscribe(loggedIn => {
            if (loggedIn) {
                this.me = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can return the name from backend while authenticating, you could inject the AuthenticationService to the NavbarComponent and bind the required name in navbar.component.html.

NavbarComponent:

```
export class NavbarComponent {
   ...
   constructor(private authservice: AuthenticationService) {}
   ...
}
```

navbar.component.html:

```
<span>Welcome {{authservice.name}}!</span>
```